# SQL don't create a table (or database first?)

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

in logcat i have this error:

```
12-05 19:20:26.696: E/SQLiteDatabase(1415): Error inserting lon=5.25 lat=7.52 name=null
12-05 19:20:26.696: E/SQLiteDatabase(1415): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: position (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO position(lon,lat,name) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

I try to insert 3 value: name,lat,lon in the table named: position. In the code i don't have any error and the app don't crash. I have attached the event of the insert of the value to a button with a onClickListener (when the user press the button,insert the value).

The code of the database creation:

> public class listagpsdb {
>
> ```
> SQLiteDatabase mDb;
> DbHelper mDbHelper;
> Context mContext;
> private static final String DB_NAME="listagps";
> private static final int DB_VERSION=1;
>
> public listagpsdb(Context ctx){
>         mContext=ctx;
>         mDbHelper=new DbHelper(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
> }
>
> public void open(){  //il database su cui agiamo è leggibile/scrivibile
>         mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
>
> }
>
> public void close(){ 
>         mDb.close();
> }
>
>
>
>
> public void insertPosition(String name,double lat, double lon){ 
>         ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
>         cv.put(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY, name);
>         cv.put(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY, lat);
>         cv.put(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY, lon);
>         mDb.insert(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE, null, cv);
> }
>
> public Cursor fetchProducts(){ 
>         return mDb.query(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,null);               
> }
>
> static class PositionsMetaData {  
>         static final String POSITIONS_TABLE = "position";
>         static final String ID = "_id";
>         static final String POSITIONS_NAME_KEY = "name";
>         static final String POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY = "lat";
>         static final String POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY = "lon";
> }
>
> private static final String POSITIONS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"  
>                 + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE + " (" 
>                 + PositionsMetaData.ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
>                 + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY + " text, "
>                 + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY + " double not null);"
>                 + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY + "double not null);";
>
> private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
>
>         public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
>                 super(context, name, factory, version);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) { 
>                 _db.execSQL(POSITIONS_TABLE_CREATE);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>
>
>         }
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

In the code you see i want to create the table only when the database are created.

This the code of the activity class:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navi);



                Button SalvaLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SalvaLocation);
                final listagpsdb db = new listagpsdb(getApplicationContext());
                SalvaLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {



                    db.open(); 

                    String name = null;
                    Double lat = 7.52;
                    Double lon = 5.25;
                    db.insertPosition(name, lat, lon);

                    db.close();

                    }
                });
```

**Now i don't understand why the database/table are not created. Anyone have an idea?**
There's a trick to see in the AVD memory if the database are created or not?

Thank's to all want to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code at `PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY`..

```
private static final String POSITIONS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"  
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE + " (" 
                + PositionsMetaData.ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY + " text, "
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY + " double not null,"
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY + " double not null);";
```

Comment: Yes i have tryed now but don't change anything,same error. I don't understand,database hate me XD

Comment: Wait,now the logcat give me a line with and error. The line 42,is this line:

`mDb.insert(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE, null, cv);`

Comment: @user1873069 : Do you need the PositionsMetaData class?? Else give directly "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"  
                + POSITIONS_TABLE + " (" ......

Comment: `private static final String POSITIONS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + POSITIONS_TABLE + "(" ID + "integer primary key autoincrement, " + POSITIONS_NAME_KEY + "text," + POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY + "double not null," + POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY + "DOUBLE NOT NULL);" ; `

Something like this,without the PositionsMetaData Class?

Comment: I try now but this format is not correctly for Eclipse,i try to understand where is the error. The class PositionMetaData give the result for each variable in the POSITION_TABLE_CREATE code.

Comment: Np and thx for your help.
Anyway,i have tried with the method you have proposed to me,but the result...is the same..: no such table: position
The db is created but not the table,i don't understand and this problem makes me creazy @_@

Comment: @user1873069 : did u delete the db and try again?? Once the db is created, then if u run by changing the code, new table will not be created..

Comment: I have tried to uninstall the application,delete the database and reinstall.Now the table are created but when i try to insert the value give the error..: table position has no column named lon.

This an infinity story..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see the Database if it have been created!..

Go to `Window -> show view -> File Explorer`,..

In that go to `data -> data -> your package name-> and Database -> Your db`

After that, you can use the SQL open db for opening yours Database and files..

Comment: Try with this simple example for yours database.. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Ok,i have controlled in my phone (not in avd) and the db are present in the folder,now the problem is why don't create the table. I have read the tutoril and the only difference i have see is the command to create the table. I have wrote in the  TABLE_CREATE = CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST you not,only CREATE TABLE

Comment: yes,i have tested in both: AVD and phone (both GS3). I have tried to chenge the sql command to create the table but nothing,the logcat give me the same error